# Chemical Elements in the Star Trek Universe

Tags: star-trek, science

Star Trek commonly refers to [chemical elements](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Elements) we "haven't yet" discovered, such as "bilitrium", "illirium", "veridium", and "yominium".

A few might correspond to isotopes found in the [Island of Stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability), but there simply isn't enough room there to account for the hundreds of extra elements present in the Star Trek universe.

Is there any hint anywhere about how these bound states form? Are they proton-neutron-electron collections or something else? Are forces other than the strong nuclear and the electromagnetic involved?

Comment: Do they *have* to be elements? Could they not be compounds? (Perhaps the "ium" [suffix](http://www.skwirk.com/p-c_s-4_u-107_t-285_c-953/naming-compounds/nsw/naming-compounds/introducing-chemistry/compounds-and-reactions) is only for elements?)

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest, but the list given in that link is called "Elements", so...

Comment: It is also possible to form 'atoms' out of particles besides protons, neutron, and electron.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_atom).    That could account for the prevalence of so many as-yet undiscovered 'elements'

Comment: The problem with exotic atoms is they are generally unstable. Apparently positronium is metastable, but that makes it essentially an explosive, because as a matter-antimatter pair, it decays into high energy photons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> A few might correspond to isotopes found in the Island of Stability, but there simply isn't enough room there to account for the hundreds of extra elements present in the Star Trek universe.

There is enough room, because these new elements invented for Star Trek aren't *in addition to* the existing elements from the real world - they *replace* many of them!

The [Star Trek periodic table](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Periodic_table) described by Memory Alpha based on images seen in the TNG episode *Rascals* is quite weird and unfamiliar to real chemists:

[image]

[image]

Elements are sorted by atomic weight, which is seemingly unrelated to atomic size and doesn't correlate (in the cases of elements that do exist in the real world) with real atomic weight.

In this table, though, nearly *all* the entries are joke elements, so perhaps we can safely ignore this as "just an in-joke" (don't kill me, all you hard-core Trekkies!) The [Starfleet Medical Reference Manual](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Fleet_Medical_Reference_Manual) has a more sensible-looking periodic table with far fewer imaginary elements:

[image]

In either case, given that there *is* still a periodic table, and its overall shape is similar to that of the real one (although some of the elements have different names), it's reasonable to conclude that atoms of different elements are made up of varying numbers of protons, neutrons, and electrons just as in the real world.

Comment: Top image is broken

Comment: You might want to consider adding [this image from Voyager](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/8/8c/Periodic_table_DS9.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20060810100117&path-prefix=en)

Comment: @Richard I think that's the one I tried to add, but couldn't get the image to come out properly.

Comment: So, at the botton of the table there are the *lanthanides*, the *actinides*, the *bo..ides* (Bo maybe borgium so borgides?). But what about the 139-140? Arent they a bit miplaced? Maybe they are the famous island of stability, but IMO they should be below.

Comment: I agree that the elements from that episode are dubious at best. Does this mean we don't have a real answer? Even that more reasonable table has elements thought to be impossible. Also -- something I forgot to mention -- the existence of over 200 elements is mentioned in an episode of Enterprise.

Comment: @Rodrigo - The Island of Stability lies somewhere between 110 and 120.

Comment: @MackTuesday Basically, yes: we don't have a real answer. Searching on the internet for "Star Trek periodic table" gives lots of results, plenty different from each other; there doesn't seem to be one canonical answer.

Comment: @MackTuesday: Well, elements up to 118 have already been observed. And some theorize that the island would be around 130. Anyway that's just a 21st century guess and probably and underestimation. I'd bet to the Star Trek scientists every time.

Comment: @Rodrigo - also, those two rows at the bottom of my feet are actually a very long row broken into to the better formatting. This follows the expected pattern of electron configurations on which our current periodic table is based.

Comment: @Rodrigo - if you review the article I link to in my original post, you'll see the island of stability indeed lies between elements 110 and 120. The isotopes  we've synthesized so far within this range of atomic numbers don't have enough neutrons to fall inside that island. That's why they're unstable.

Comment: There is a scene in TNG *Night Terrors* where Data shows Troi a number of elements: http://i.giphy.com/l0Hlvoj8nieU2TjjO.gif

Answer (score -5):

This is just cannon, if we do become an interstellar species the elements may change due to the involvement as a species (what we get from the universe may change and elements may evolve as well). Or we may be able to break elements even further, (for example helium is an element but what in the future we discover helium can be broken down even further and thus a new element is defined where helium may be no more than a bi-product)

Comment: It doesn't work that way...

Comment: Literally no part of this besides "This is just cannon" carries any truth at all.

Comment: We already know what happens when helium is broken down. The result is hydrogen.

Comment: In what sense would the elements evolve?

Comment: Elements can't evolve. Elements are defined by the number of protons, and we already know all the ones up to 118. So there is absolutely no way to create new elements by breaking down known ones.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish and even that part is misspelled.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish: plus it’s “[canon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canon#Noun)”, not “[cannon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cannon#Noun)”, so even that part is technically wrong.

Comment: Also: hi @Berry! Welcome to the site. You might want to take a look at [the tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get an idea of how the site works — despite appearances, it’s a question-and-answer site, not a discussion forum.